# Normal force at the inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises

A particle mass $m$ moves down a frictionless inclined plane. Does a normal force cancels a normal component of $m$ **g**?

Comment: Thanks. I am ok with drawing a diagram and replacing a force by its components, but I am not sure about intensity of a normal force. I have read in the article you attached that normal component of weight balances a normal force. Does it mean that $F_{normal}$ and normal component has equal intensity, but opposite directions? (I am not a physics student, so I don't know much about these stuffs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the free body representation.  If you have a mass on the inclined plane at some angle $\theta$, the weight (mg) is in the -y direction.  The normal force points NORMAL to the surface, which means it will have both an x and a y component.  Through some simple trig, we can see that $F_{normal}=mg cos(\theta)$.  This is not completely mg, because the other component ($mg sin(\theta)$) is the force responsible for the mass sliding down the inclined plane.

So I am not completely sure what you mean by `a normal force cancels a normal component of m g` but there are different components to each.

Comment: I have inclined plane at angle $\theta$ to the surface. I took a coordinate system such that inclined plane lies on x-axes. Then I wrote $m$ **g** as $m$ **g** $=mg\sin \theta$ **i** $-mg\cos \theta$ **j**. If I take such coordinate system, $F_{normal}$ would have a direction of $y$-axes, right? What I meant by "cancels" is that I have written that $m$ **g** $+$ **N** $=mg\sin \theta$ **i**, which made me conclude that $F_{normal} =mg \cos \theta$ **j**, i.e. that it is equal to normal component of $m$ *g*, but opposite direction.

Comment: That is all correct

Comment: Does it ALWAYS hold that $F_{normal}$ has equal intensity as normal component has, but it has the opposite direction?

Comment: Well, the $F_{Normal}$ does not have the same intensity as the weight.  If that we the case, the block would not slide down.  I assume you mean by `has equal intensity as normal component has` that it equals the weight?  This is not true.  F normal is the normal component so yes(?) they are equal

Comment: No, I don't mean that it is equal to weight but to normal component of weight. If they are equal (which I can see from the problem I wrote above, and you said it was all correct), there is still another component of the weight that force the block to move.

Comment: Okay, so you are asking if $F_{normal}$ always equals the normal component of the weight?

Comment: Yes, I am asking that.

Comment: In this geometry, that is correct.